# TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

While touring the "class" column, I want to change the value to "01" if the data value is "one", "02" if it is "two", and "03" if it is "three", what's the problem?

```
# Import Packages
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# dataset upload
df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
df = df.rename(columns={'pclass':'passenger_class','sex':'gender','age':'old'})
for x in df['class']:
    if df.iloc[x] == 'First':
      print('01')
    elif df.iloc[x] == 'Second':
      x = '02'
    elif df.iloc[x] =='Third':
      x = '03'
df
```

Get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

Comment: I mean the error message is pretty self-explanatory. Maybe use .loc instead of .iloc As iloc looks for an integer value and loc works with keywords

Comment: Get an Error

KeyError: 'Third'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in comment, [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)  only takes integers as [indexers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing). Or, given how you iterate over `df['class']`, it turns out that your `x`s are strings of characters. Hence the [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) you get.

That being said, if you want to replace your occurrence by something else, what about using [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), as follows:

```
>>> df['class'].map({'First': '01', 'Second': '02', 'Third': '03'})
0      03
1      01
2      03
3      01
4      03
       ..
886    02
887    01
888    03
889    01
890    03
Name: class, Length: 891, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['01', '02', '03']
```

Comment: The cause was 'string' data. Thanks to you, i solved it! Thank you so much.